# Straight cracks on drywall ceiling

Tags: drywall, ceiling, crack

Long straight cracks in same section of the drywall ceiling. Is this due to poor drywall installation or structural?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually just due to two pieces of drywall moving slightly relative to each other. Tape, mud, paint.

Comment: It may be because of the type of tape used. I stopped using fiberglass mesh tape when I started seeing this occur. If you look real close in the gap, you should see fine lines going across the crack, this will be the threads of the mesh tape, Check closer and please confirm.

Comment: Shoot some properly exposed photos up close. This is badly underexposed and too far away.

Comment: Added additional close up photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poor installation.

From the looks of it, this joint was not taped before drywall mudding began.

Drywall joints are taped and mudded as part of the finishing process, this prevents this type of cracking among other things.

You will likely need to have a drywall contractor come out and get it fixed up for you, unless you are comfortable doing it on your own.